# Jquery working in eclipse browser but not in any other browser

Tags: jquery

In the below HTML, i am trying to display questions one by one. Questions Array is from a json and contains all the question objects. I use Eclipse PDT and wamp server. When i run the below code in my eclipse browser, the navigation between questions is working fine. But when i run the same code in Google Chrome, submit button action is called on the tap of every other button tap also. I found it using the chrome developer tools.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $.getJSON('http://localhost/3s/Sample/JsonCreation.php', function(data)
    {   
        questionsArray = data;

        displayQuestionJS(questionsArray[currentQuestionNo], document);
    }); 

    $('form').on('submit', function(event)
            {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        $('#sampleDiv').load("UserReport.html");        
            });

});

$(document).on('click', 'button', function()
{
    if ($(this).attr('id') == "markForReview" || $(this).attr('id') == "nextQuestion")  
    {
        //NAVIGATION FOR NEXT QUESTION
        currentQuestionNo++;
        //RESETTING OPTIONS
        $("input:radio").prop('checked', false);
    }
    else if ($(this).attr('id') == "clearResponse")
    {
        $("input:radio").prop('checked', false);
    }
    else
    {
        //RESETTING OPTIONS
        $("input:radio").prop('checked', false);

        currentQuestionNo = ($(this).attr('id') - 1);
    }
    displayQuestionJS(questionsArray[currentQuestionNo], document);
});

function displayQuestionJS(currentQuestion, document) 
{
    document.getElementById('questionNumber').innerText  = currentQuestion.questionNumber;
    document.getElementById('questionDescription').innerText  = currentQuestion.quesDesc;
    $('label[for=optionA]').html(currentQuestion.optionA);
    $('#optionA').attr('value','A');

    $('label[for=optionB]').html(currentQuestion.optionB);
    $('#optionB').attr('value','B');

    $('label[for=optionC]').html(currentQuestion.optionC);
    $('#optionC').attr('value','C');

}
</script>
```

HTML

```
<div id="sampleDiv">

<br />
<br />

<form method="post" name="formQuestion">

<label id="questionNumber"></label>. &nbsp;
<label id="questionDescription"></label>   <br />
<input type="radio" id="optionA" name="options"> </input> <label for="optionA"></label> <br />
<input type="radio" id="optionB" name="options"> </input> <label for="optionB"></label> <br />
<input type="radio" id="optionC" name="options"> </input> <label for="optionC"></label> <br />

<button id="markForReview">Mark for Review and Next</button>
<button id="clearResponse">Clear Response</button>
<button id="nextQuestion">Save and Next</button>

<br />
<br />

<input type="submit" id="submitButton" name="submitTest" value="Submit"></input>
</form>


</div>
```

Please let me know what should be done...

Comment: use <input type="button" /> instead of <button>

Comment: U r awesome.... It works! What was the issue. Please explain.